# error - lengths differ when trying to integrate (but lengths are the same)

Tags: r, integration

I have data :

```
Date                 Value
17/12/17 8:39:45    1144.5783
17/12/17 8:40:02    1646.5863
17/12/17 8:40:15    1104.4177
17/12/17 8:40:30    1244.9799
17/12/17 8:40:45    1084.3373
17/12/17 8:41:00    1285.1406
17/12/17 8:41:15    1144.5783
17/12/17 8:41:30    1124498
17/12/17 8:41:45    1265.0602
17/12/17 8:42:00    1124498
17/12/17 8:42:15    1144.5783
17/12/17 8:42:30    1164.6586
17/12/17 8:42:45    1084.3373
17/12/17 8:43:00    1184739
17/12/17 8:43:15    1064257
17/12/17 8:43:30    1164.6586
17/12/17 8:43:45    1184739
17/12/17 8:44:00    1244.9799
```

I want to compute the integral during the date.
My real data consists of 3124 rows.

```
library(lubridate)
library(MESS)

thedata <- read.csv('data.csv')  

datetime <- dmy_hms(as.character(thedata$Date))
time_length_data <- time_length(interval(datetime[1] , datetime[18]), "second")
# data is gathered by almost every 15 sec
divide_data <- 1:(time_length_data / 15)
# I am ommiting a few rows in order to have the same length as "sec" matrix below.
divide_data <- divide_data[1:18]

# this contains the values and has length 18
sec <- as.numeric(as.matrix(thedata[2]))

res <- auc(divide_data, sec, from = min(divide_data), to = max(divide_data), type = 'spline', absolutearea = TRUE)
```

When I try to execute res, it gives me:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab= FALSE): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

but the lengths are the same.

Comment: Could you please update your question based on the small subsample? Forget about your real data with 3124 rows.

Comment: Where is your `auc`-function from?

Comment: I am assuming your `auc` is from `MESS` but you should include that in your example.

Comment: @kath:Yes, it is from MESS.

Comment: @Eumenedies:Yes.it is from MESS

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is indeed a bug. Fixed in the development version of `MESS` so install with `devtools::install_github("ekstroem/MESS")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the `MESS` package with the `absolutearea` flag set to `TRUE`.

If you look at the code for `auc`:

```
if (absolutearea)
    myfunction <- function(x) { abs(splinefun(x, y, method="natural")) }
else
    myfunction <- splinefun(x, y, method="natural")

res <- integrate(myfunction, lower=from, upper=to)$value
```

Two problems arise here, `x` is specified twice and `splinefun` returns a function, not a value.

If `absolutearea` is false then `myfunction` is a spline function trained on the `auc` arguments `x` and `y`.

If `absolutearea` is true then `myfunction` is the absolute value of the spline function (note function, not value returned) trained on the anonymous function's `x` argument and the `auc` function's `y` argument.

The `integrate` function is passing a series of values to `myfunction`. If `absolutearea` is false then `myfunction` returns the value of the spline at each of those values. If `absolutearea` is true then `myfunction` returns a nonsensical absolute value of a function. It never throws that error (non numerical argument...) because it errors the first time when `x` (the values being passed to the anonymous function by `integrate`) is a different length to `y` (the y values passed to the `auc` function).

Comment: Perfect answer and explanation of the problem. A user (you?) submitted a fix and the new version should be up and running. Thanks!